# Can you stack Combat Expertise and Power Attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, attack

Are you allowed to stack the feats of Power Attack and Combat Expertise in a single round?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes.**

Both penalties are untyped, and therefore stack with each other. You may have a hard time hitting anything, though!

Answer (score 8):

Yes, but the penalties also stack, so it usually isn't done.

Comment: In certain circumstances I've seen it done.  There are things in the DMG with a high CR and a low AC.  Fighters usually have VERY high attack bonuses in the mid to high levels so they parcel out the bonus a couple ways.

Comment: Well yes, especially if you are using abilities which let you transfer the penalty to something you care about less or using magic items to decrease the importance of your base attack bonus. Both of these are, as I understand, common in higher level optimized play, but, for the sort of person asking this question, I didn't think it would come up often soon.

Comment: Actually our 9th level 2-handed Ranger/Fighter was looking to do this.  The power attack increased his damage output, but the baddies were brutal when they connected (think trolls in construct form).

Answer (score -3):

I did this with a critfisher. You hit if you roll within the 15-20 you crit at. So it doesn't matter what your to hit is. Attacked with +0/+0/-5/-5 at level 10 and still came out on top

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site; we may be a little different from what you are used to: this is not a discussion forum. All answers are required to answer the question; this doesn’t, really, except that it implies the answer is yes (or, at least, it was yes for this character). Furthermore, all answers are required to back up what they claim: even if we accept your implied answer of yes, you still give no reason why we should accept that answer. Please see the [Tour] for more on how we are different from discussion forums, and how to write good answers.